# copying files in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to learn input output in sml.In an effort to copy strings of `ls`that are the same as `s1` into the file `l2` I did the following.I am getting some errors I can not really understand.Can someone help me out.

```
fun test(l2:string,ls:string list,s1:string) = if (String.isSubstring(s1 hd(ls))) then

                       (TextIO.openOut l2; TextIO.inputLine hd(ls))::test(l2,tl(ls),s1) else 

                       test(l2,tl(ls),s1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some general hints:

1. Name your variables something meaningful, like `filename`, `lines` and `line`.
2. The function `TextIO.inputLine` takes as argument a value of type `instream`.
3. When you write `TextIO.inputLine hd(ls)`, what this is actually interpreted as is
   `(TextIO.inputLine hd) ls`, which means "treat `hd` as if it were an `instream` and
   try and read a line from it, take that line and treat it as if it were a function,
   and apply it on `ls`", which is of course complete nonsense.

   The proper parenthesising in this case would be `TextIO.inputLine (hd ls)`, which
   still does not make sense, since we decided that `ls` is a `string list`, and so `hd ls`
   will be a `string` and not an `instream`.

Here is something that resembles what you want to do, but opposite:

```
(* Open a file, read each line from file and return those that contain mySubstr *)
fun test (filename, mySubstr) =
    let val instr = TextIO.openIn filename
        fun loop () = case TextIO.inputLine instr of
                          SOME line => if String.isSubstring mySubstr line
                                       then line :: loop () else loop ()
                        | NONE => []
        val lines = loop ()
        val _ = TextIO.closeIn instr
    in lines end
```

You need to use `TextIO.openOut` and `TextIO.output` instead. `TextIO.inputLine` is one that reads from files.

Comment: this helped,but i don't understand `val _ = TextIO.closeIn instr`.I didn't know a function can take `()` as argument.Can you also say something about `()` here.

Comment: It sounds like you wish to read a book about Standard ML. `()` is the single value for the type `unit`. Please go and look it up.